# too many network request logs for one single admob ad

Tags: android, admob

I have loaded admob ad for only one time, but I am getting too many request logs for single ad. can any one suggest me why i am getting too many logs

After loading ad I have started network tracing for ads to test it.
here is how we can start network tracing https://developers.google.com/admob/android/network-tracing#enable_tracing

> I/Ads     ( 4660): GMA Debug BEGIN
>
> I/Ads     ( 4660): GMA Debug CONTENT {"timestamp":1510679993741,...}
>
> I/Ads     ( 4660): GMA Debug FINISH

I am getting these logs for single ad more than 10 times with different parameters in GMA Debug CONTENT

can anyone let me know why I am getting these logs for a single ad

This is my class

```
public class AdView extends FrameLayout {

    private PublisherAdView mAdView;
    private boolean mIsLoaded;

    public AdView(@NonNull final Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public AdView(@NonNull final Context context, @Nullable final AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public AdView(@NonNull final Context context, @Nullable final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context, null);
    }

    public AdView(@NonNull final Context context, final String unitId) {
        super(context, null, 0);
        init(context, unitId);
    }

    public AdView(@NonNull final Context context, final String unitId, final ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams) {
        this(context, unitId);
        setMargins(layoutParams);
    }

    public void init(final Context context, final String unitId) {
        //TODO: inflating xml and setAdUnitId causing crash java.lang.IllegalStateException: The ad unit ID can only be set once on AdView., investigation required if we can do that or not
        initializeAdView(context, unitId, 0);
    }

    public void init(final Context context, final String unitId, final int colorId) {
        initializeAdView(context, unitId, colorId);
    }

    private void initializeAdView(final Context context, final String unitId, final int colorId) {
        mAdView = new PublisherAdView(context);
        mAdView.setAdSizes(AdSize.MEDIUM_RECTANGLE);
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(unitId)) {
            mAdView.setAdUnitId(unitId);
        }
        if (colorId == 0) {
            mAdView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.f1_cream));
        } else {
            mAdView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, colorId));
        }
        mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                if (colorId == 0) {
                    mAdView.setBackground(null);
                }
            }
        });
        setDescendantFocusability(FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
        addView(mAdView);
}

    public void setScrollView(EdgeGlowNestedScrollView mScrollView) {
        //mScrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(() -> showAdWhenFullyVisible());
    }


    private void setMargins(final ViewGroup.LayoutParams parentLayoutParams) {
        final LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) parentLayoutParams;
        final int margin = (int) getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.margin_normal);
        layoutParams.setMargins(0, margin, 0, margin);
        setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }

    public void load() {
        if (!mAdView.isActivated()) {

            mAdView.loadAd(new PublisherAdRequest.Builder().build());

        }
    }

    public void showAdWhenFullyVisible() {
        final Rect scrollBounds = new Rect();
        if (getGlobalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)) {
            load();
        }
    }
}
```

this is how i am calling it

```
        final AdView adView = ((AdView) holder.itemView);
        final Context context = holder.itemView.getContext();
        adView.init(context, getAdUnitId(context, position));
       adView.load();
```

Comment: How many times per minute do you get these messages ?

Comment: Also please show the code where you create and add the `AdView`.

Comment: @Benoit at least 20 times

Comment: Can you show the context where `AdView` is instantiated and public methods called ?

Comment: here it is how i called  ```final AdViewHolder holder = (AdViewHolder) holderBase;
        final AdView adView = ((AdView) holder.itemView);
        final Context context = holder.itemView.getContext();
        adView.init(context, getAdUnitId(context, position));
        adView.load(); ```

Comment: Add some tracing in the `init(Context context, String unitId)` method - I think it's called more often than what you think...

Comment: That's good if you are getting more requests for a single ad. The inventory will return ads sooner than usual.